# getchar in python returns permission denied (andorid 8.0)

Tags: android, python, getchar, termux

I am working on `termux`, **android 8.0.**

I am using the following implementation of `getchar`:

```
class _Getch:
    """Gets a single character from standard input.  Does not echo to the
screen."""
    def __init__(self):
        try:
            self.impl = _GetchWindows()
        except ImportError:
            self.impl = _GetchUnix()

    def __call__(self): return self.impl()


class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import sys, tty, termios
        fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
        old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
        try:
            tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
            ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
        finally:
            termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
```

The call to **tcsetattr** returns permission denied. A new `security feature` I guess.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "piano.py", line 103, in <module>
    char=getch()
  File "piano.py", line 21, in __call__
    def __call__(self): return self.impl()
  File "piano.py", line 33, in __call__
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.6/tty.py", line 28, in setraw
    tcsetattr(fd, when, mode)
termios.error: (13, 'Permission denied')
```

How to overcome this? (readchar package raises the same error)

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the full error traceback!

Comment: There's a bug report about it: https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1359

Comment: Yes, it is true. I saw it.  I hope for a practical solution like adding permission to the application or using another method for getting a single char. Although, changing the mode of operation does seem like a natural way to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is my solution.

```
class _GetchUnix:
    def __init__(self):
        import tty, sys

    def __call__(self):
        import subprocess,sys
        t=subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c','read -s -n1 ans; echo $ans'],stdin=sys.stdin)
        return chr(t[0])
```

Comment: there doesnt seem to be bash on android 8.0; i ran this code on my phone and got `No such file or directory: 'bash'`

Comment: I work on termux which is an environment that is more similar to a regular linux OS (like Ubuntu) . With what do you work?